# I want to make a custom slider in my App

Tags: iphone, uislider

I am looking to code a custom slider which should be able to show a box on the slider's location with the slider's value. 
Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a post from Alexander Repty on how he achieved something similar in Folio Case.

[Using KVO to annotate custom UISliders](http://blog.proculo.de/archives/182-Using-KVO-to-annotate-UISliders.html)